# Populate a value in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Excel spreadsheet and I have 3 columns. column A, column B, Column C.

In column B if there is a value 1 then in Column C it should populate as True and if in column B value is 0 then in C it should be False.
How do I do this in MS Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
=IF(B2=0, FALSE, TRUE)
```

As per comment request

```
=IF(B2=0, "0%", "100%")
```

Comment: Astander, I have one last question. How do I populate 100% if the value is 1 and 0% if the value is 0

Answer (score 3):

In C1 enter

```
=(B1 = 1)
```

or

```
=(B1 <> 0)
```

and duplicate it until the end of column.